# GTM trigger not firing on custom pop-up screen

Tags: google-tag-manager

On our site, https://www.nzmotorhomerentals.co.nz/ we have created an tag in our GTM container to track Adwords conversion, however are having issues getting the tag to fire when a user clicks the Confirm button at the end of the booking process. We believe this is due to the pop-up screen once a user clicks on a search result.

At the moment the booking process is as follows:
1. User lands on homepage or other landing page.
2. User enters search criteria, and clicks 'Search'
3. User lands on /results page and then clicks 'Select' on chosen vehicle
4. Pop-up window appears and user clicks 'Go to final step'
5. User lands on final booking page and clicks 'Confirm'. When a user clicks 'Confirm' this is when we want the tag to fire.

We have tried a wide range of trigger variables with no luck. We managed to get a tag to fire on step 1 when a user clicks 'Search' as a way of troubleshooting, however have not been able to get any tags to fire once a user lands on the /results page and further into the booking flow.

All content from /results onward is a custom piece of html that is pulling from a broker site (this website is an affiliate model). We are wondering if Google Manager is able to read this custom code at all.

Any assistance on how variables to set to fire this trigger is much appreciated.

Comment: Is the pop up an Iframe?

Comment: @Jesse yes, booking form is an Iframe

Comment: Unfortunately the tag manager won’t be able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

your booking form is implemented in the iframe and is unavailable to Tag Manager.